# sails:how to avoid same name while uploading a file

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, sails.js, waterline

i'm doing file upload in sails.js.I just uploaded a file to my local path.
but the problem is when i upload a same file again means it will override the existing file.

```
var uploadFile= req.file('SourceFileImport');

         uploadFile.upload
         ({
                // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~10MB
                maxBytes: 10000000,saveAs: function(uploadFile, cb) {cb(null, uploadFile.filename); },dirname: '../../assets/uploads'
            },function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
            if (err) 
            {
                console.log("error");
                return res.negotiate(err);
            }
            // If no files were uploaded, respond with an error.
            if (uploadedFiles.length === 0)
            {
                return res.badRequest('No file was uploaded');
            }
            else 
            {
                    console.log(uploadedFiles[0].fd);
            }
```

I need to change the file name dynamically while uploading a file with same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are providing the name to save the file as `uploadFile.filename`, which will be whatever the file is named before uploading. You simply need to make the name something unique. The easiest way to do this is to include the current timestamp. So change, `uploadFile.filename` to `Date.now() + uploadFile.filename`

```
maxBytes: 10000000,
saveAs: function(uploadFile, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + uploadFile.filename); 
},
dirname: '../../assets/uploads'
```

This will add the current timestamp to the filename, which will ensure each name is unique and the files don't overwrite each other.

Comment: how to get that cb later for saving it in the db? Is there another way than this: var fn= uploadedFiles[0].fd.split('\\'); fileName = fn[fn.lenght-1]; ?